# How tocreating Django model form to take input from users

Tags: django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I am Django beginner and I have tried the following to create three fields Django model forms to take input from model (to let user to post on my blog) but it is not working, please help me.

I have tried the following to create three fields Django model forms to take input from model (to let user to post on myblog) but it is not working, please help me. I expect to have form with three fields (title, slug, and content) on my template to take input from users.

models.py

```
`class post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="blog_posts")
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=STATUS, default=0)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_on']

    def __str__(self):
       return self.title`
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import Comment, post
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = post
        fields = ["title", "slug", "content"]
```

views.py

```
`from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404,redirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib import messages
from django.views import generic
from .forms import CommentForm, PostForm
from . models import post
from .forms import *
def post_cont(request):
    template_name = 'index.html'
    if request.method == 'POST':
       post_form = PostForm(request.POST)
       if post_form.is_valid():
          new_post = post_form.save()
          return redirect(reverse('post_detail', args=[new_post.slug]))
       else:
        messages.error(request, 'Form is not valid')
    else:
      post_form = PostForm()
      return render(request, template_name, {'post_form': post_form})`
```

Comment: Answer please please please